# Azure Retrieve Secret from key vault

Tags: azure, azure-python-sdk

I am following the Microsoft documentation to retrieve secrets from a key vault using python sdk.

The code and explanation offered by Microsoft leads to this code:

```
import os
import cmd
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


keyvault_name = f'https://<Keyvaultname>.vault.azure.net/'
KeyVaultName = "<Keyvaultname>"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = SecretClient(vault_url=keyvault_name, credential=credential)



print(" done.")

print(f"Retrieving your secret from {KeyVaultName}.")

retrieved_secret = client.get_secret("test")

print(f"Your secret is '{retrieved_secret.value}'.")
```

According to my understanding, the `DefaultCredentials` are the one configured in the `az login` which is fine, my code runs just fine but I keep getting this message in the terminal.

```
 done.
Retrieving your secret from <KeyvaultName>.
EnvironmentCredential.get_token failed: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
ImdsCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
SharedTokenCacheCredential.get_token failed: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple accounts
were found in the cache. Use username and tenant id to disambiguate.
```

I presume that this `warnings` are due the fact that I have multiple subscription in my azure portal.

I was wondering, how can I get rid of those and set the credentials for only a single subscription?

Thank you so much for any help and explanation you can offer me.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're able to get the secrets properly. Only thing you're concerned about is this warning message. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I am able to get the secret back but that warning keeps getting in the way

Comment: Also, you would always want to use Azure CLI credentials in your code?

Comment: In the future I would like to move this logic to a azure function

Comment: Then in that case, I would not worry about this warning. Essentially when you use `DefaultAzureCredential`, the SDK tries a number of credential options in a particular order. It moves from one to next if one credential option fails. You can see that order here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, I would not worry about this warning. When you use `DefaultAzureCredential`, SDK tries the following credential options in that order ([`Reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet)):

- EnvironmentCredential
- ManagedIdentityCredential
- SharedTokenCacheCredential
- VisualStudioCredential
- VisualStudioCodeCredential
- AzureCliCredential
- AzurePowerShellCredential
- InteractiveBrowserCredential

SDK moves from one credential options to another if that credential option fails. The warning message is just a way for the SDK to tell you what all credential options it has tried.

However if you still want to get rid of this message, there are a few options available to you:

- Exclude the credential options that you do not want SDK to try when using `DefaultAzureCredential`. You can specify those via `exclude_xxx_credential` option in the constructor. For example, if you want to exclude `EnvironmentCredential`, you would specify `exclude_environment_credential=True` in the `DefaultAzureCredential` constructor. SDK will skip those credential methods. Please see this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-python#constructor) for all constructor options.
- Use specific credential option. For example, if you always want to use Azure CLI credentials, then instead of using DefaultAzureCredential you can use [`AzureCliCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.azureclicredential?view=azure-python).